# Why do we need to take the closure in the definition of projective closure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=Z(I)$ be an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Given the standard covering $\{U_i\}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and the homeomorphism $\varphi_0:U_0\to\mathbb{A}^n$, the projective closure of $X$ is defined as $\overline{X}:=\overline{\varphi_0^{-1}(X)}\subseteq U_0$.

My confusion comes from the fact that $\varphi_0$ is an homeomorphism: since $X$ is closed shouldn't $\varphi_0^{-1}(X)$ be closed too and taking its closure unnecessary?

Comment: I think the closure needs to be taken in $\mathbb{P}^n$, not in $U_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse image of $X$ is closed in $U_0$, but not necessarily closed in $\mathbb P^n$. $\overline{\varphi_0^{-1}(X)} \subset U_0$ is plain wrong.

For example $U_0$ itself is closed in $U_0$, but not closed in $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: So simple.. Thanks!